# Why `declare global` does not work but `declare module does`?

Tags: typescript

originally `response.locals` has type `Record<string, any>`, i want to add my custom type that something like below:

```
type locals = { redirect_to: string }
```

in our codebase we have similar case for `Request` object, the solution is create `*.d.ts` with this content:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            locals?: {
                session_id?: string;
            };
        }

        // new type i've added:
        export interface Request {
            locals?: {
                redirect_to?: string;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work for Response, i got solution with below but i don't fully understand what is the difference between Request and Response. What i've found is `Request` does not have `locals` field but `Response` does. Turns out the code above is working if i add new field instead of trying to override existing one. But i still don't quite understand why.

Below is my solution, anyone know why it is working?

```
declare module 'express' {
    export interface Response {
        locals?: {
            redirect_to: string;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this depend on `express`? If so you might want to tag the question as such. If not, could you provide a [mre] that doesn't seem to depend on it?  Ideally we'd be able to play around with it in our own IDEs without dependencies unrelated to the question